# Opinions/headers for splitting an application into front-end/back-end (not user/admin, but ui/logic)

Tags: java, php, api, architecture

I am building a new web application and playing around with the architecture and would like some opinions about splitting UI and business logic and running them on separate servers.

This means that if someone requests a page, the front end will itself request the data from a back-end server and then not actually perform any calculations/logic but just use the data to populate a template and then respond with that.

- Back-End: Java + JAX-WS
- Front-End: [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) 3.1 (PHP)
- Data Interchange Format: JSON

**Advantages**:

- clear separation of logic and UI
- ability to choose language/framework best suited for either end
- possibility to add logic/UI servers depending on which one is the bottleneck in case of performance issues
- possibility to make the API publicly available without any extra work (pseudo-internal requests will go to the same API as requests from third-part applications)
- ability to change (if need be) the framework/language of either side without having to edit the other
- ability to specify different server hardware according to the needs of the logic/UI application
- better security (if API private) (??)

**Disadvantages**:

- latency (??)
- more servers

So what do you think? Is this a good idea? I haven't been able to find much information so far but my guess is that many big sites do it this way, right? How will performance be affected (I am thinking of running it on EC2)? What are further advantages/disadvantages? Any thoughts on the  languages/frameworks choices?

Comment: I'd say you've hit it on the head with both the pros and cons, o1iver.   Not much to add.

Comment: Any ideas about how badly this will affect latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar architectural pattern is often employed, though generally the UI part is often moved to the client. So you have a backend that responds with JSON, a quick http server with full-blown caching (and that can use html5 app caching as well) and a rich javascript client which requests the JSON from the backend and builds the UI.

More on this pattern: http://www.metaskills.net/2008/05/24/the-ajax-head-design-pattern/

The main negative of the approach is that is generally more work in the beginning - if you don't need an external API then using a simpler architecture will be easier to program.

Comment: Thanks for that link and for the pointer. I guess this pattern is even more extreme than what I envisioned in that it literally removes the need for just about any front-end server stuff. I guess you could remove it almost entirely and just serve static pages with JS that then handles the entire requesting. But doesn't that mean that you cannot hide the API? If you use a server-side controller that passes on the ui/data it can authenticate secretly, but you can't hide that with JS...

Comment: Well you can use an authenticated connection with the client, but yes, your API endpoints will be visible. But as I said that if you don't want to expose the API anyway, then there's little point in doing it.

Comment: The API will quite certainly be public, so I am building for that possibility. I don't really mind that the API is visible anyway, but an important question is how do I know if the request is coming from a client on our application or from a third party client? I obviously want to make sure that in cases of heavy load the former have priority. Placing a server-side controller in the middle gives me the possibility of identifying myself to the back-end as such... Any ideas as to how to do that?

Comment: I can't really think of a 100% reliable way to do that (might be good for a new question). You might check the request headers for the referrer or have a private (meaning simply non-documented) parameter set. Spoof-able, sure, but probably not a horrific problem.

Comment: Yep I thought about the non-documented parameter as well, but the problem is, like you said, that since the js in visible its spoofable...will post a new question!

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to employ the idea of keeping your servers stateless and let the client side handle any state. 
This simplifies the whole load-balancing and fail-over stuff and makes you think about a more resource-oriented architecture.

And if you are set on JSON already, you might want to explore the idea of NOT mapping POJOS to your data and use a document store like MongoDB or CouchDB to access JSON data directly.

Comment: Client side state management: for sure. Do you mean getting rid of the logic completely? I need to perform some data analysis before I can respond to a client request...But I will be using MongoDB for persistence

Comment: no, logic is fine, but holding state on the server between calls from the client is problematic.  If you hold this 'state' in MongoDB, I wouldn't call it state and that is fine.

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly. I understand the problem of holding 'state' (information, ex: logged in/not logged in, about a client's current session) between requests. I mean in a single server application this is not a problem (php sessions or something) but I understand that it is a problem as soon as you have multiple servers behind a load balancer. So do you mean that I should store the equivalent of sessions in MongoDB because it then does not matter if the next request goes to the same or another server (it can just retrieve session info from the DB)?

Comment: I would try to not have any session data in the first place. For example, authentication/authorization information should be transmitted by the calling client, so you don't need session information to identify the user.  My guess is that some UI related session data can be kept on the client or saved to the server when needed.  Other session data is better stored on the persistence backend (and thus made available to all your severs).

Comment: Yeah I will definitely build it up that way... didn't think of that before but now the memories of setting up load balancing come back :-) Thanks for the info!